# Primary accounts?

Tags: apps, microsoft-account, parental-control

We've given our daughter my old 635, or we will be soon. I set up her microsoft account, added her to 'My family' etc. I want to download some apps for her, so I've put my pay monthly sim in her phone. I went to download Minecraft: Pocket Edition (same as mine & my partner's first download, we've all been playing it since it was first released in beta!) and it keeps coming up with a notice saying 'my family is not set up'. It is, I know it is. I'm guessing there's protection to stop children running up massive contract phone bills? So I tried to add my account so I don't have that issue. The problem is it's still using my daughters account, so it's still asking to have my family set up.

I haven't downloaded any apps or anything so if I can't find a way around it I'll just do a hard reset & start from the beginning using my account to start with, but I'd rather not if I can help it. I have tried un-syncing my daughters account.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'd make sure that paid downloads are allowed in the My Family settings, just in case. Otherwise you'll have to do a reset and set up the phone with a different account. This issue is fixed in Windows 10 Mobile, where you can use multiple accounts with the Store.